# How to add option with spesific index listview

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have listview.     How to add option 3 with correct index ?

```
 <select size="12" id="test" class="form-control">
           <option> 1 </option>  
           <option> 2 </option>  
           <option> 4 </option>  
           <option> 5 </option>  
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var newOpt = $('<option>3</option>');
newOpt.insertAfter($('#test option').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() == (+newOpt.text() - 1);
}))
```

**Demo**

```js
var newOpt = $('<option>3</option>');
newOpt.insertAfter($('#test option').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() == (+newOpt.text() - 1);
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select size="12" id="test" class="form-control">
  <option> 1 </option>
  <option> 2 </option>
  <option> 4 </option>
  <option> 5 </option>
</select>
```

**Demo 2**

This one is a bit more dynamic.

```
var newOpt = $('<option>3</option>');
newOpt.insertAfter($('#test option').filter(function() {
  var n = +$(this).text();
  var n1 = $(this).next().text() || 999;

  return (n < +newOpt.text() && +newOpt.text() < n1)
}))
```

```js
var newOpt = $('<option>11</option>');
newOpt.insertAfter($('#test option').filter(function() {
  var n = +$(this).text();
  var n1 = $(this).next().text() || 999;

  return (n < +newOpt.text() && +newOpt.text() < n1)
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select size="12" id="test" class="form-control">
  <option> 1 </option>
  <option> 4 </option>
  <option> 6 </option>
  <option> 22 </option>
</select>
```